# What is the real characteristic equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My book says that you form the character equation as 
$\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda I - A
\end{vmatrix}$. However I see occasionally on stack exchange and other resources that define the character equation as $\begin{vmatrix}A - \lambda I\end{vmatrix}$. Why does this appear to be such a trivial matter? Here are some examples below where I have found the latter being used.

[Geometric multiplicity of repeated Eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417976/geometric-multiplicity-of-repeated-eigenvalues)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors  (under "Eigenvalues and the characteristic polynomial"

Answer (score 0):

The two only differ by a factor of $(-1)^n$, so it's not a big deal. In my opinion, the better convention is $\det (\lambda I - A)$, because that guarantees that the characteristic polynomial is always monic (has leading coefficient $1$). But it is a convention; both conventions are basically fine.